# Woocommerce - remove product-thumbnail from product category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've like to remove the product thumbnails (not display:none, but completely remove action) on Product Category Pages. Any suggestions?

I tried adding the following in my Wordpress functions file but didn't work:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );
```

Answer (score 2):

The hook used on the category page is: `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title`.

So you need to do the following:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove thumbnail category, go to file `content-product-cat.php` and remove the following code:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );
```